# How to get the table name from the function argument in postgres so that the table name is used to create a table in the function

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a function in Postgres for creating a table, the table name has to be given by the user at the time of the function call

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mnth(
tablename text
)
RETURNS void as $$
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE monthly.||tablename||
(
row_id text,
left_row text,
right_row text,
left_plus text
);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

During the function call, the name given by the user will be the name of the table that will be created in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `EXECUTE format`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mnth(
tablename text
)
RETURNS void as $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format ( 
'CREATE TABLE %I.%I
(
 row_id text,
 left_row text,
 right_row text,
 left_plus text
)' , 'monthly',tablename );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: if I want to select some rows from the table name which is from argument how can I get that

Comment: @Thivar : Any new requirement should be asked as a separate question and not continued in the comment section.